# Firefox event.target issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, events

Generally speaking, and if I recall correctly I've used this at least a dozen times before, but for some god-forsaken reason it doesn't work since this morning... Somebody have a clue?

**[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jdwbz48f/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<button id="testID" onclick="foo()">
test me
</button>

<button id="testID2" onclick="foo(this)">
test me 2
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function foo(event){
alert(event.target.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you pass `undefined` to `event`. In the second example, you pass the button to `event`.

If you want the event object, then you have to pass the event object. That's called `event`, but I don't know how standard it is for it to be created for intrinsic event attributes.

In general, you are better off binding your event handlers with JavaScript.

```js
function foo(event){
    alert(event.target.id);
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", foo); 
}
```

```html
<button id="testID">
test me
</button>

<button id="testID2">
test me 2
</button>
```

Comment: Okay, tested and works, I've read other examples, people talk about having to define an event in the function declaration as a parameter, I did that but no effect, i guess I need to explicitly tell it to have it as an argument as well.